# Two Methods That Throws Exceptions How To Differentiate between them

Tags: c#, exception

I have a try catch block that surrounds two methods that can each throw ArgumentException.

I want to differentiate between the exceptions, so that I can return better error message for the user.
What will be the best way to do it? (I want to refrain from surrounding it with two separate try catch blocks).

```
try
{
    var store = storeFactory.Create(id); // Can Throw ArgumentException
    var order = await store.GetOrderAsync(orderId); //Can Throw ArgumentException

    return Ok(order);
}
catch (ArgumentException ex)
{
    //TODO: How To Tell Which Methods Throw The Exception (Create Or GetOrderAsync)
    return NotFound("Store Id Was Not Found");
    return NotFound("Order Id Was Not Found");
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `throw new ArgumentException(message); return NotFound(ex.Message)`?

Comment: That's an option that I considered, but i want somehow to massage the message so it will be more user friendly (let's say I want to provide more details in the massaged message)

Comment: Do you control both methods? What should these ids both be ? Int? Are the formats valid and throw the error or should these perhaps really be something else?

Comment: I don't control those two methods. those are both Int. I didn't understand the last question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply separate the `try` block into two `try` blocks:

```cs
try
{
    var store = storeFactory.Create(id); // Can Throw ArgumentException
    try
    {
       var order = await store.GetOrderAsync(orderId); //Can Throw ArgumentException

       return Ok(order);
    }
    catch ( ArgumentException ex )
    {
       return NotFound("Order Id Was Not Found");
    }
}
catch (ArgumentException ex)
{
    //TODO: How To Tell Which Methods Throw The Exception (Create Or GetOrderAsync)
    return NotFound("Store Id Was Not Found");
}
```

Even better solution however would be to create a new type of exception for both cases, for example:

```
public class OrderNotFoundException : Exception
```

and

```
public class StoreNotFoundException : Exception
```

And then modify your methods to throw these descriptive errors instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm trying to avoid from the first solution. As for the second the code is already closed can't change the inner exceptions. I thought of another solution, Maybe there is an attribute in the Exception object that tells you which object throw the exception that I can use it.

Comment: I am afraid that without access to the inner code or being able to differentiate between the exceptions somehow, there is nothing better than the first solution...

Comment: Thanks, so i will stick with this.

Comment: As far as Exception handling goes, I would really adivce to read those two Articles: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET Your exampels is one of hte rare cases where you might actually be adding Semantic Information to the whole thing by wrapping your own sub-exceptions around it.